# How do I make a responsive div resize in only one horizontal direction?

Tags: css

I want to add an increasing amount of text using Javascript into a div.

When I change the the text inside the div in the html, it is responsive, but it responds by increasing the width in both directions rather than only pushing the text to the left, which is the desired behavior.

I have thought about using float, but as there are no elements to the left or right of this div, I'm not sure it would make sense in this situation.

Here is the link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/sentedelviento/pen/bZzPrO?editors=1100

html:

```
<body>
  <div id='parent'>
    <div id='test'>Will remain centered no matter</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#parent {
  width: auto; height: 10%;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#test {
  width: auto; height: auto;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;

}
```

Comment: Did you try using margin: 0 auto for centering div?

Comment: yes? How would that solve the problem?

Comment: It will stand centered ;p adding max-width also could help
But maybe I don't catch your problem, can you add some more description for desire solution?

Comment: If you click this link, when you click on buttons on the calculator, the numbers in the history expand to the left. I want to replicate this but I'm not sure how: https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/rLJZrA/

Comment: The calculator demo you posted has a div with a fixed width and doesn't expand. The text is expanding to the left because it has a `text-align:right` property that aligns text to the right of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZzXPw?editors=1100

```
#test {
  max-width: 80%; height: 80%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

You could also use absolute position but must remember to align to right:

```
#test {
  max-width: 80%; height: 80%;
  margin-top: 1%;

  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 10%;
  position:absolute;
  right: 0%;
}
```